# Retrieving checkbox input (Groovy Html MarkupBuilder + SpringBoot)

Tags: forms, spring-boot, groovy

I'm a newbie in Groovy and SpringBoot, but have to use these technologies in my work.
I have a User and Role classes, they don't have any relations inside classes. In Get-action in Controller I pass User and List of all possible roles to the form.
Controller class:

```
@GetMapping
public String edit(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    model.addAttribute("roles", roleRepository.findAll());
    return "edit";
}
```

My edit.tpl file:

```
...
form(..., method:'post'){
    label(for:'username', 'Username: ')
    input(type:'text', id:'username', name:'username', value:user.username)
    label("Add roles: ")br()
    roles.each {role -> 
        label(for:role.name, role.name)
        input(type:'checkbox', id:role.name, name:role.name, value:role.name)
        br()
    }
    input(type:'hidden', id:'_method', name:'_method', value:'put')
    input(type:'submit', class:'btn btn-info', value:'Save')
}
```

I want to retrieve all the checked Roles.
Like that:
  role_1  unchecked
  role_2  checked
  role_3  checked
List = [role_2, role_3]; 
I get the User like that:

```
@PutMapping("{id}")
public String update(@Valid User user, @PathVariable Long id){
    user.setId(id);
    userRepository.save(user);
    return "redirect:/users";
}
```

And also in future I want to somehow check the current active Roles when passing them to the form.
Like that:
Current active roles are: role_2, role_3.
When I make a Get-request to show the form for editing, i have role_1 unchecked, and role_2 and role_3 checked.
My classes are as follows:

```
public class Role{
    private String name;
    //getters, setters, etc.
}

public class User{
    @NotBlank(message="Please enter username")
    private String username;
    //getters, setters, etc.
}
```

Thanks for any help!! :)

Comment: what is the association between User and Role? one-to-many?

Comment: In real project there's a 3d class - UserRole, that contains User and Role (to make the structure as flat as possible). User can have many Roles, right.

Comment: showing checked/unchecke roles can look like `input type:'checkbox', name:role.name, checked:role in user.userRoles*.role`

Comment: thanks for the idea! I'll try it :) Now I'm using a simple if-conditional and I pass the additional list of current Roles the User have to check/left unchecked. ```if(currentRoles.contains(role)) {input(..., checked:'checked')} else {input(.....)}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to get necessary information from the checkbox inputs: 
use the @RequestParam annotation the following way:

Controller.java

```
public String update(@Valid User user, @RequestParam("roleIDs") List<Long> roles, @PathVariable Long id){
    System.out.println(roles); //-the checked roles
    return "redirect: /users";
}
```

Groovy .tpl file:

```
roles.each {role -> 
    label(for:role.name, role.name)
    input(type:'checkbox', id:role.name, name:'roleIDs', value:role.id)
    br()
}
```

Seems like I haven't googled the right question :)